differential equations, substitution suggested by the equation
I took my examination in differential equations earlier; i would've gotten a perfect score, but i tripped in this problem:
$$(1+5y\sin x)dy + y^4\cos xdx = 0$$
I used substitution suggested by the equation: $w = \sin x$, $dw = \cos x dx$. I transformed it into a linear D.E., however, i was stuck in the integration of the right part:
$$\int -y^{-4}e^{-5/2y^{-2}}dy$$
i tried using integration by parts, but i used substitution to simplify the function: $u = y^{-1}$, $du = -y^{-2}dy$, resulting in $$\int [u^2e^{-5/2u^2}du]. $$
i hoped to get a repeating integral, but the sign i got for the integral have the same sign, making it cancel with each other.
is my method wrong, or are there any method to evaluate this differential equation?

Please use MathJax to format your equations. I've edited the post, but you should check if it is right.

Your method is fine. Possibly your instructor intended to check your understanding of the fundamental theorem of calculus to write the solution in terms of a definite integral,$$e^{\tfrac5{2y^2}} \sin (x(y)) = C - \int_{y_0}^y e^{\tfrac5{2t^2}},\frac{dt}{t^4}$$

Wow, can you explain it a little further? I want to understand on how I can write my solution in that way.

It's just applying the FTC:$$f'(y)=g(y) \implies f(y) - f(y_0) = \int_{y_0}^y g(t),dt$$Here $C$ plays the role of $f(y_0)$, and $y_0\neq0$ is an arbitrarily chosen constant.

You got rightfully stuck on that integral because you can't integrate it, it can only be solved numericallly. There must have been a typo in the question. My guess is that the question should have been:
$$
(1+5y^2\sin x)dy+y^4\cos xdx=0.
$$
Which would have the solution:
$$
\dfrac{e^\frac{-5}{y}(2y^2+10y+25)}{125y^2}+e^\frac{-5}{y}\sin x=c.
$$

I hope so, because I know that the question was inspired from a book I read before, which is (1+3xsiny)dx$ - x^2cosy dy$ = 0
